# java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java

I try to instantiate JasperReport object but it get error Exception in thread

```
"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.actionFailed(ApplicationAction.java:859)
    at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.noProxyActionPerformed(ApplicationAction.java:665)
    at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.actionPerformed(ApplicationAction.java:698)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
Hibernate: select categories0_.CategoryID as Category1_11_0_, categories0_.parent as parent2_11_0_, categories0_.CategoryName as Category3_11_0_, categories0_.Description as Descript4_11_0_ from categories categories0_ where categories0_.CategoryID=?
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:369)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1020)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1064)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6636)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2764)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Hibernate: select categories0_.CategoryID as Category1_11_0_, categories0_.parent as parent2_11_0_, categories0_.CategoryName as Category3_11_0_, categories0_.Description as Descript4_11_0_ from categories categories0_ where categories0_.CategoryID=?
EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.noProxyActionPerformed(ApplicationAction.java:662)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.deleteSourceFiles(JRAbstractCompiler.java:407)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:281)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:358)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:344)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:609)
    at forms.EvidentaMijloaceFixe.ImprimaListaOMVSD(EvidentaMijloaceFixe.java:1537)
    ... 44 more
```

This is my code:

```
public void ImprimaListaOMVSD() {   titluRaport = "LISTA FISELOR OMVSD";
    list = HibernateUtil.getInstance().getOMVSDList();
    try {
        jasperReportOrders = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("reports/ListaMF.jrxml"));

    } catch (JRException ex) {
        System.out.print(ex.toString());
        Logger.getLogger(EvidentaMijloaceFixe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {

        mapParams.put("denEntit", entitatea.getCompanyName());
        mapParams.put("catObiect", titluRaport);
        mapParams.put("codFisc", entitatea.getRegistrationCode());
        mapParams.put("dataDin", jDateDin.getDate());
        mapParams.put("dataPina", jDatePina.getDate());
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReportOrders, mapParams, ds);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        System.err.print(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code. BTW JasperReport objects you do not have to instantiate, they are created by the JasperReports compilerm, either at comile time or at runtime by code...

Comment: How I can post my code?

Answer (score 0):

apparently the path of your tables you use for query the database is null. Try to look your code at the tables references of your database. If you can you can post a piece of code I will take a look to be more precise.